# How do you run multiple inputs in eclipse at once?

Tags: eclipse, input

I'm trying to input a set of numbers and alphabets into eclipse such as this

n
5
x
s
v
x
s
c
a
.6

m
5
3
50
4
2
3
0
-500
2
3
1
0
2
5
4
3
0
x
p
s
c
v
a
.7
s
a

is there anyway to run all of these inputs at once? because i am typing them in individually ( for example: n "enter" 5 "enter" x "enter" and so on)? i am looking for ways to do this SPECIFICALLY on eclipse so that i can see where exactly my code went wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When do you need this input? While running your application or in an editor or what?